# Limiting a user to enter 1 decimal value in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

The requirement is to limit user from not entering more than 1 decimal value in a numeric/decimal edit text field. That said, I also need to limit the number entry to 6 Max digits. eg. 999999.9

If a user enters numeric alone - then I should be able to limit the user to 6 digits Max, but should allow "." and decimal number(if entered by the user).

I am not sure, how to do this. Any help and reference will be of great help.

Comment: Use TextWatcher on your EditText. http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/using-textwatcher-in-android.html

Comment: I kinda figured that I have to make use of TextWatcher, but the problem still lies on how to dynamically restrict user in case mentioned above. i.e. If number only restrict to 6 chars and decimal 1 char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe some implementation similar to this? I'm pretty sure it can be optimized a lot!

```
EditText et;
.....
// force number input type on edittext
et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
et.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(et));
```

where:

```
class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    private EditText et;
    private String tmp = "";
    private int moveCaretTo;
    private static final int INTEGER_CONSTRAINT = 6;
    private static final int FRACTION_CONSTRAINT = 1;
    private static final int MAX_LENGTH = INTEGER_CONSTRAINT + FRACTION_CONSTRAINT + 1;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText et) {
        this.et = et;
        nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(INTEGER_CONSTRAINT);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(FRACTION_CONSTRAINT);
        nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    }

    public int countOccurrences(String str, char c) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        et.removeTextChangedListener(this); // remove to prevent stackoverflow
        String ss = s.toString();
        int len = ss.length();
        int dots = countOccurrences(ss, '.');
        boolean shouldParse = dots <= 1 && (dots == 0 ? len != (INTEGER_CONSTRAINT + 1) : len < (MAX_LENGTH + 1));
        if (shouldParse) {
            if (len > 1 && ss.lastIndexOf(".") != len - 1) {
                try {
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(ss);
                    if (d != null) {
                        et.setText(nf.format(d));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
        } else {
            et.setText(tmp);
        }
        et.addTextChangedListener(this); // reset listener

        //tried to fix caret positioning after key type:
        if (et.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            if (dots == 0 && len >= INTEGER_CONSTRAINT && moveCaretTo > INTEGER_CONSTRAINT) {
                moveCaretTo = INTEGER_CONSTRAINT;
            } else if (dots > 0 && len >= (MAX_LENGTH) && moveCaretTo > (MAX_LENGTH)) {
                moveCaretTo = MAX_LENGTH;
            }
            try {
                et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length());
                // et.setSelection(moveCaretTo); <- almost had it :))
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        moveCaretTo = et.getSelectionEnd();
        tmp = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int length = et.getText().toString().length();
        if (length > 0) {
            moveCaretTo = start + count - before;
        }
    }
}
```

Not 100% but you can use as a base and build on top of it ;)

**EDIT:** tried to polishing setting the caret position after text changed but it was more difficult than I estimated and reverted to setting the caret at the end after each char input. I left the code I started on for the caret maybe you can improve it?

Comment: Code works great. Except, if Number reaches 6, I can't add the decimal value after that.

Comment: Yeah, I have the exact same code. To be clear, the delimiting works perfectly fine. But once number reaches 6 character length, '.' delimiter does not come up on the edit text. Do you see that happening? By the way, thanks a lot in helping me in this.

Comment: @ Marci, Its my bad. I had set the Max length as 6 in the layout.xml. Now that I have removed it, it works as desired. However, there are few other minor issues like the text getting replaced, which I will try to debug. Any input from you will be of great help. At this point, I guess you have helped me a lot. Accepting the answer and will reward the point. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks, at the same time if I can .. I will post the code back :)

Comment: It looks like 'nf.format(d)' clips off the 1st character from the string, whenever user enters a new character in the edittext.

Comment: @ Marci, Thanks for the help. I have transferred the bounty points :). I still have the above issues, working on them.

Comment: @sku I fixed the issue but now the caret position bugs me and I messed around a bit with it but its very tricky and gave up. Check the edited code ;)

Comment: Great solution. I ended up using a variant with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small mistake in above answer

I edited that one use the below code.

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DecimalTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    private EditText editText;
    private String temp = "";
    private int moveCaretTo;
    private int integerConstraint;
    private int fractionConstraint;
    private int maxLength;

    /**
     * Add a text watcher to Edit text for decimal formats
     * 
     * @param editText
     *            EditText to add DecimalTextWatcher
     * @param before
     *            digits before decimal point
     * @param after
     *            digits after decimal point
     */
    public DecimalTextWatcher(EditText editText, int before, int after) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.integerConstraint = before;
        this.fractionConstraint = after;
        this.maxLength = before + after + 1;
        numberFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(integerConstraint);
        numberFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(fractionConstraint);
        numberFormat.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
    }

    private int countOccurrences(String str, char c) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == c) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // remove to prevent StackOverFlowException
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        String ss = s.toString();
        int len = ss.length();
        int dots = countOccurrences(ss, '.');
        boolean shouldParse = dots <= 1 && (dots == 0 ? len != (integerConstraint + 1) : len < (maxLength + 1));
        boolean x = false;
        if (dots == 1) {
            int indexOf = ss.indexOf('.');
            try {
                if (ss.charAt(indexOf + 1) == '0') {
                    shouldParse = false;
                    x = true;
                    if (ss.substring(indexOf).length() > 2) {
                        shouldParse = true;
                        x = false;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        if (shouldParse) {
            if (len > 1 && ss.lastIndexOf(".") != len - 1) {
                try {
                    Double d = Double.parseDouble(ss);
                    if (d != null) {
                        editText.setText(numberFormat.format(d));
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (x) {
                editText.setText(ss);
            } else {
                editText.setText(temp);
            }
        }
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this); // reset listener

        // tried to fix caret positioning after key type:
        if (editText.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
            if (dots == 0 && len >= integerConstraint && moveCaretTo > integerConstraint) {
                moveCaretTo = integerConstraint;
            } else if (dots > 0 && len >= (maxLength) && moveCaretTo > (maxLength)) {
                moveCaretTo = maxLength;
            }
            try {
                editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
                // et.setSelection(moveCaretTo); <- almost had it :))
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        moveCaretTo = editText.getSelectionEnd();
        temp = s.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int length = editText.getText().toString().length();
        if (length > 0) {
            moveCaretTo = start + count - before;
        }
    }
}
```

> use it as below..

```
itemCostEditText.addTextChangedListener(new DecimalTextWatcher(itemCostEditText, 6, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of TextWatcher's afterTextChanged/onTextChanged methods to get notified for text changes and DecimalFormat to format input text

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html